# In MS Excel what formula can be used to calculate growth when CAGR for the period is already given?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what my Excel sheet looks like

[image: CAGR]

I've been provided the $ figure for the year 2020 in **cell B5** and the CAGR % is reflected in **cell L5**.

The $ figure for 2020 is 342.9 ( Cell B5) and the CAGR growth rate per year is 92.60% (Cell L5)

What formula can be used to calculate the $ figure for the years 2021 through 2028 ?

Comment: `=B5*$L5` and drag down and accross. But your CAGR's don't look like CAGR's - maybe forgot to subtract 1? That's why I am suggesting straight multiplication.

Comment: ^ In other words, is South/Latin America growing at `104.2%` per year, or just `4.2%` per year?

Comment: If those are true CAGR's, then just do `=B5*(1+$L5)` and drag down and across.

Comment: @BigBen South/Latin America is growing at 104.20% CAGR between 2020 and 2028.

Comment: Wow that's fast. So use the 2nd formula.